# Рационально ли использование фреймфорка при разработке одностраничника на PHP?

Tags: php, yii, symfony2, symfony

Добрый день!

Недавно освоил PHP. Сейчас есть заказ на разработку лендинга.

Рационально ли было бы применять какой-либо фреймворк, вроде Yii или Symfony.

Или все пишется спокойно на обычном PHP

Comment: Лендинг можно вообще на чистом HTML написать(ну и js немножко)

Comment: а за этим одностраничником много функционала?

Comment: Чаще всего для лендинга нужен `JS` + `HTML` и никакго `PHP`.

Comment: Пушкой по воробьям. Требуется функционал небольшой, а фреймворк предоставляет все 33 удовольствия. Хотя если есть желание, место и необходимость получить опыт работы с каркасом - пожалуйста.

Comment: какой будет функционал? Лендинг только для чтения, или там оставлять заказы, email'ы в подписку, сообщения с сайта, оплата, смс, боты для мессенджеров и пр. навороты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от задач, которые хочется решить на стороне бэкэнда. Скорее всего, вам хватит всего функционала фреймворка. Я работал с Yii и знаю, что в нем уже есть масса хэлперов, позволяющих формировать красиво даты, суммы и прочее. Так же, имеется функционал защиты от csrf и инъекций.

Я не вижу ничего плохого в том, что в одностраничнике кто-то использует фреймворк для экономии времени на разработку и тестирование. Как минимум, вы не потратите время на создание базовой структуры, фильтры и валидаторы входящих данных (заполнение форм).

Если использовать кэширование при наличии выборки из sql, то можно легко и быстро сэкономить ресурсы.

Однако, нет никакого смысла в использовании фреймворка, если вы пишете на серверной стороне только какой-нибудь render('template') и больше ничего.